# How to get key of multidimensional array in foreach loop using php?

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I need to print the student name and the mark from the following array for a given subject:

```
$marks = [
    "john" => ["physics" => 30, "maths" => 55, "chemistry" => 66],
    "jack" => ["physics" => 44, "maths" => 19, "chemistry" => 87],
    "mark" => ["physics" => 77, "maths" => 66, "chemistry" => 67],
];
```

I understand that if I do `echo $marks['john']['chemistry'];` it will print the mark for the student/subject, but how should I approach a **foreach** loop for displaying all students and their scores for chemistry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In php [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) you can get key of current item like this

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$item){...}
```

Also use it like bottom code

```
foreach ($marks as $name=>$scores){
    echo $name .":". $scores["chemistry"];
}
```

See result of code in [demo](https://3v4l.org/0OI56)

Comment: This was an eye opener for me. I'd always use: foreach $array as $key => $value for a single dimension array but used: foreach $multiarray as $array.. and didn't stop to think you could get $key => $array in the second case. Excellent, thanks.